# Trying to assign multiple keyof to a dynamic desctured object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here's a working example to illustrate my question.

```
interface Definition {
  oneTitle: string
  oneDescription: string
  twoTitle: string
  twoDescription: string
}

const obj = {
  oneTitle: 'Title 1',
  oneDescription: 'Desc 1',
  twoTitle: 'Title 2',
  twoDescription: 'Desc 2'
}

type Keys = 'one' | 'two'

const keys: Keys[] = [
  'one',
  'two'
]

keys.forEach((key) => {
  const {
    [`${key}Title` as keyof Definition]: title,
    [`${key}Description` as keyof Definition]: description,
  } = obj
})
```

As you can see, there's a dynamic object descturation, eg. `` [`${key}Title`] ``. I'd like to know if there is in that case a way in Typescript to avoid to define multipe times `as keyof Definition` for every key?

I've tried the following things without any success.

```
const {
  [`${key}Title`]: title,
  [`${key}Description`]: description,
}: Record<keyof Definition, Definition> = config
```

```
const {
  [`${key}Title`]: title,
  [`${key}Description`]: description,
}: {[key in keyof Definition]: Definition} = config
```

Indeed, as I'm getting that error in both cases `has no matching index signature for type 'string`, it's seems that Typescript is interpreting the dynamic key as a string rather than a keyof of the Definition type.

Thanks for your help (:

Answer (score 1):

It's not a huge improvement, but if you prevent automatic type widening in 2 places, you can remove the need for `as keyof Definition`, though the code will still be a bit repetitive. Declare the `keys` array `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `string[]`, and declare the property accessor `as const` so it also doesn't get widened to `string`.

```
const keys = [
  'one',
  'two'
] as const;

keys.forEach((key) => {
  const {
    [`${key}Title` as const]: title,
    [`${key}Description` as const]: description,
  } = obj
})
```

Comment: I remember seeing a hotly debated issue in the TS github about possibly adding an option to disable type widening everywhere - not implemented yet AFAIK, but it'd be useful for more functional styles we see nowadays, which would make all of this unnecessary, but I can't find a link to it again after searching for a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that it really suits in that case, I would like to find a way whithout defining the type for every key.

Comment: I don't think getting things shorter is possible at the moment, but I might be wrong. But, TypeScript has problems with dynamic keys in general, making code more convoluted. I'd highly recommend instead changing your data structure so that the keys aren't dynamic, if at all possible.